# Calculate days between an interval with intck

Tags: sas

I'm trying to calculate the days between two dates for example 01JAN2020-30NOV2021 but without success. I tried: days=intck("days", start, end+1) but it does not work. Dates are numeric after PROC CONTENTS. Is this the problem? As an example I showed one date but I have to calculate days for 3000 records.

Thank you in advance

Comment: 'Without Success' does not give us much information. Do you get an error? Or simply an unexpected result?

Comment: a column with missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no interval named DAYS.  You could use the DAY interval.

```
days=intck("day", start, end+1);
```

But since DATE values are just number of days you can also just subtract.

```
days=end - start + 1 ;
```